# how can i get the list of all files Inside a folder

Tags: java, android, android-studio

please how can I list all files inside a folder?
I try to do that with that code

```
    File theFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator +"TestFolder");

    if(theFolder.exists())
    {
        Log.d("theFolder", "theFolderExiste ");
        File [] files = theFolder.listFiles();

        Log.d("Files", "files: "+files.length);
        
        for(File file : files)
        {
            Log.d("file ", "file name : "+file.getName());
        }
        

    }else
        {
            Log.d("theFolder", "we dont have that folder ");
        }
```

but hi give me that error
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
at com.joshuabutton.documentscanner.DisplayListOfFiles.onCreate(DisplayListOfFiles.java:76)

and I have files inside that folder as you can see in that pic [image]

Comment: The test folder exists but it doesn't contain any files. So your array files is null and you are getting the exception.

Comment: The javadoc for listFiles() says: Returns:
An array of abstract pathnames denoting the files and directories in the directory denoted by this abstract pathname. The array will be empty if the directory is empty. Returns null if this abstract pathname does not denote a directory, or if an I/O error occurs.

Comment: `if (files==null) return;`. Add that to your code and you will not have a NullPointerException. Display a toast to inform the user when null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to access the files, the permissions must be given in the manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
Try this:

String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Pictures";
Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
File directory = new File(path);
File[] files = directory.listFiles();
Log.d("Files", "Size: "+ files.length);
for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++)
{
    Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + files[i].getName());
}
```

Comment: i did that and I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

There's two things you need to take in consideration.

1 - You need a [read storage permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` to be able to read data that your app did not create

2 - Even with read storage permission, newer versions of android, do not allow to read folders this direct, check out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UnJ3amzJM94&ab_channel=AndroidDevelopers), it might help you

Comment: thank you but I already have that permission to access to the external storage but I still have the same problem